# const pointer members - Immutable item list

Tags: c, pointers, constants

Below is the `List` representation,

```
typedef struct List{

  void **array;
  int lastItemPosition;
  int size;
}List;
```

---

where `list->array` is allocated with `const void *` collection, to maintain immutability of items,

```
list->array = malloc(INITIAL_LIST_SIZE*sizeof(const void*));
```

---

But assigning a `const void *` item in `list->array`,

```
void arrayInsertItem(List *arrayList, const void *newItem){
  ...
   arrayList->array[++(arrayList->lastItemPosition)] = newItem;
  ...
}
```

---

gives error:

```
 error: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Werror=discarded-qualifiers]
   arrayList->array[++(arrayList->lastItemPosition)] = newItem;
```

### ^

Is it required to declare `const void **array` in `List`to maintain immutability of items?

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> To maintain, immutability, const void * type item is stored in the collection list->array. But gives error:

Thats what your after, but you've not declared the array as such:

> void **array;

Try changing to:

> const void **array;

Answer (score 0):

> *where list->array is allocated with const void * collection*

That does not change the type of `array`, anyway.

As you have defined `void **array;` as the member, `array` is of type pointer to `void *`, and `array[i]` would be of type `void *`.

As you're going to assign a `const void *`, the element should also have the same *type qualifier*.

Change

```
 void **array;
```

to

```
 const void **array;
```

Comment: OK. So, do I need to maintain `const void **` to maintain immutability?